# I can't run youtube exoplayer with android studio java

Tags: java, url, youtube, exoplayer

I want to start the video in the youtube url in Exo player, but the code does not work. I tried different methods and libraries, but none of them met what I needed. I don't want to use Youtube API My goal is to run the video from any YouTube URL in the video player. What do you suggest for this or how do I need to change my code?

```
package com.yazilimevi.youview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaItem;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MergingMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;

import at.huber.youtubeExtractor.VideoMeta;
import at.huber.youtubeExtractor.YouTubeExtractor;
import at.huber.youtubeExtractor.YtFile;

public class Video extends Fragment {
    PlayerView playerView;
    SimpleExoPlayer player;
    boolean playWhenReady = true;
    int currentWindow = 0;
    long playbackPosition = 0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video, container, false);
        playerView = view.findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        initPlayer();
        return view;
    }

    private void initPlayer() {
        player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(getContext()).build();
        playerView.setPlayer(player);

        String youtubeUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxeKPU0MBU8";
        String videoId = extractVideoId(youtubeUrl);

        if (videoId != null) {
            playYoutubeVideo(videoId);
            System.out.println("YouTube Video ID: " + videoId);
        } else {
            // geçerli bir video ID'si çıkaramadık
            System.out.println("Geçerli bir YouTube Video ID'si çıkaramadık.");
        }

        player.prepare(); // Eğer bu satır yoksa ekle
    }



    private String extractVideoId(String youtubeUrl) {
        String videoId = null;

        String pattern = "(?<=watch\\?v=|/videos/|embed\\/|youtu.be\\/|\\/v\\/|\\/e\\/|watch\\?v%3D|watch\\?feature=player_embedded&v=|%2Fvideos%2F|embed%\u200C2F|youtu.be%2F|%2Fv%2F)[^#\\&\\?\\n]*";
        String[] patterns = {
                "^(https?\\:\\/\\/)?(www\\.)?(youtube\\.com|youtu\\.?be)\\/(watch\\?v=|embed\\/|v\\/|e\\/|watch\\?feature=player_embedded&v=|%2Fvideos%2F|embed%\u200C2F|youtu.be%2F|%2Fv%2F)[^#\\&\\?\\n]*[^#?\\n]*",
                "^https?\\:\\/\\/(www\\.)?youtu\\.be\\/([^#\\&\\?\\n]*)",
                "^https?\\:\\/\\/www\\.youtube\\.com\\/v\\/([^#\\&\\?\\n]*)",
                "^https?\\:\\/\\/www\\.youtube\\.com\\/user\\/[^\\?\\n]*",
                "^https?\\:\\/\\/www\\.youtube\\.com\\/[^\\&\\?\\n]*"
        };

        for (String p : patterns) {
            if (youtubeUrl != null && youtubeUrl.trim().length() > 0 && youtubeUrl.matches(p)) {
                String[] splitArr = youtubeUrl.split("[^\\w-]");
                for (String split : splitArr) {
                    if (split.length() == 11) {
                        videoId = split;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return videoId;
    }


    private void playYoutubeVideo(String videoId) {
      /*  new YouTubeExtractor(getContext()) {
            @Override
            protected void onExtractionComplete(SparseArray<YtFile> ytFiles, VideoMeta videoMeta) {
                if (ytFiles != null) {
                    int videoTag = 137;
                    int audioTag = 140;
                    MediaSource audioSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource
                            .Factory(new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory())
                            .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(ytFiles.get(audioTag).getUrl()));
                    MediaSource videoSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource
                            .Factory(new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory())
                            .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(ytFiles.get(videoTag).getUrl()));
                    player.setMediaSource(new MergingMediaSource(
                            true, videoSource, audioSource), true
                    );
                    player.prepare();
                    player.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);
                    player.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("ytFiles boş");
                }

            }
        }.extract("dxeKPU0MBU8" , false, false);*/
        new YouTubeExtractor(getContext()) {
            @Override
            protected void onExtractionComplete(SparseArray<YtFile> ytFiles, VideoMeta videoMeta) {
                try {
                    if (ytFiles != null && ytFiles.size() > 0) {
                        int videoTag = 137;
                        int audioTag = 140;
                        MediaSource audioSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource
                                .Factory(new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory())
                                .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(ytFiles.get(audioTag).getUrl()));
                        MediaSource videoSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource
                                .Factory(new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory())
                                .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(ytFiles.get(videoTag).getUrl()));
                        player.setMediaSource(new MergingMediaSource(
                                true, videoSource, audioSource), true
                        );
                        player.prepare();
                        player.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);
                        player.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition);
                    } else {
                        logErrorSources(ytFiles, videoMeta);
                        String errorMessage = getSpecificErrorMessage(null); // Exception olmadan çağır
                        System.out.println("YouTubeExtractor Hata: Video dosyaları alınamadı. " + errorMessage);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logErrorSources(ytFiles, videoMeta);
                    String errorMessage = getSpecificErrorMessage(e); // Exception ile çağır
                    System.out.println("YouTubeExtractor Hata: Video dosyaları alınamadı. " + errorMessage);
                }
            }

        }.extract("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xpk2c6W8wA", false, false);
    }
    private void logErrorSources(SparseArray<YtFile> ytFiles, VideoMeta videoMeta) {
        System.out.println("Hata Kaynakları:");
        if (ytFiles == null) {
            System.out.println("ytFiles: null");
        } else {
            System.out.println("ytFiles Size: " + ytFiles.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < ytFiles.size(); i++) {
                int key = ytFiles.keyAt(i);
                YtFile ytFile = ytFiles.get(key);
                System.out.println("YtFile Key: " + key + ", Url: " + (ytFile != null ? ytFile.getUrl() : "null"));
            }
        }

        if (videoMeta == null) {
            System.out.println("videoMeta: null");
        } else {
            System.out.println("videoMeta Video ID: " + videoMeta.getVideoId());
            // Diğer videoMeta özelliklerini loglamak için gerekirse buraya ekleyebilirsiniz.
        }
    }

    private String getSpecificErrorMessage(Exception exception) {
        if (exception != null) {
            return exception.getMessage(); // Exception'ın kendi mesajını al
        } else {
            return "Bilinmeyen bir hata oluştu.";
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (Util.SDK_INT >= 24) {
            initPlayer();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        if (Util.SDK_INT >= 24) {
            releasePlayer();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    private void releasePlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
            playWhenReady = player.getPlayWhenReady();
            playbackPosition = player.getCurrentPosition();
            currentWindow = player.getCurrentWindowIndex();
            player.release();
            player = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (Util.SDK_INT < 24 || player == null) {
            initPlayer();
            hideSystemUI();
        }
    }

    private void hideSystemUI() {
        playerView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE |
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY |
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (Util.SDK_INT < 24) {
            releasePlayer();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).